# Резонность использования SQLite

Tags: база-данных, django, sqlite

Написал на django небольшое приложение для офиса, там в базе есть три таблицы, две маленькие (ожидается до 100 записей), и одна больше (на данный момент есть больше 100 записей, и ожидается увеличение постепенно понемногу, может быть до нескольких тысяч записей в будущем).

Есть ли смысл использовать для этого SQLite (читал что для веб приложений не особо производительна и настраиваемая она, но интересует мнение для требуемых обьемов) так как она простая в использовании, или же все таки стоит выбрать что то более производительное?

Comment: sqlite в джанге предназначена только для окружения разработчика и ни в каком продакшене её использовать не стоит

Comment: @andreymal даже если данное приложение предназначено для внутреннего использования в офисе и к-во пользователей будет один или несколько человек?

Comment: По-хорошему да, по-плохому — проверяйте производительность для себя самостоятельно, вам может и пойдёт :)

Comment: @andreymal на самом деле производительность в данном случае и не нужна особо (ну если не идет речь о долгой загрузке страницы в несколько секунд или больше), главнее в данном случае удобство и переносимость.

Comment: По удобству и переносимости sqlite всех уделывает, да

Comment: Есть проекты, в которых sqlite вполне достаточно, особенно если ее регулярно обслуживать. Но если хочется забыть о проблемах возникающих с sqlite со временем - лучше использовать другие БД. Предпочтение postgresql

Comment: Под ваши задачи sqlite вполне подойдёт, только бэкап не забывайте делать.Ваши несколько тысяч записей скорее всего закэшируются в памяти и обращения к диску будут чаще всего только при обновлениях. Перенести даные в другую базу всегда успеете. При желании, тот же mysql например можно настроить так, что он будет медленее sqlite, так что не ищите себе лишний раз сложностей.

Answer (score 2):

При объемах в несколько тысяч записей, вам меньше всего стоит задумываться о производительности. Тут на первый план выйдет удобство использования конкретно для вас.

Comment: тоесть можно спокойно использовать sqlite? Насколько трудно перенести при надобности данные из sqlite в другую бд?

Comment: @Oleksii, зависит от вашего проекта, от... от.... Но три таблицы и несколько тысяч записей, серьезно, эти данные можно набить вручную.

Comment: @Mirdin есть опыт набивания такого количества данных? :)

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич, однажды на одном промышленном предприятии, где сервера были подключены в одну сеть с цехами, накрылись эти самые сервера, в результате "небольшого включения" нового оборудования. В результате, я мог наблюдать как 7 человек, в течении 2 дней восстанавливают базу 1С за 8 лет с бумажных носителей... А тут всего несколько тысяч строк.

Comment: @Mirdin То есть бэкапов никто не делал, и сканеры тогда еще не изобрели? :)

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич, бэкапы хранились на серверах, на других, конечно, но подключенных к той же проводке... трехфазный ток творит чудеса :) особенно если его подключить к заземлению... и к нулю тоже :) З.Ы, сканеры тоже не любят 360 :(

Answer (score 0):

Для небольших проектов можно использовать SQLite, если планируется хранить небольшое количество записей, к примеру, настройки. В прод советую использовать PostreSQL, либо MySQL. Postgres хвалят больше, конечно.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite долго пишет в файл. То есть нет виртуального образа. Нужно работать напрямую с файлом. Но на чтение работает очень неплохо, особенно если расположена ssd.

То есть, конечно, ей можно пользоваться, даже нужно.

И на мой взгляд не стоит небольшим сайтам, если там нет конфиденциальной информации, вообще заморачиваться с полноценными и многофункциональными бд.

Comment: Не пугайте топикстартера. Sqlite пишет очень быстро, если делать [много insert в одной транзакции](https://sqlite.org/faq.html#q19). К тому же, режим [WAL](https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html) реализован давно и работает хорошо.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, я конечно мог что-то и пропутить, но вы попробуйте сделать 100 000 записей на постргесе и на sqlite, разница не то что существенная, она огромная.

Comment: Конечно, всё зависит от типа данных в колонках, от наличия ключей, индексов, триггеров и т. п. Однако, навскидку, сто тысяч строк в sqlite вставится примерно за секунду. Автору вопроса при его объёмах производительности гарантированно хватит.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, это каким способом, можно сделать за секунду? Очень интересно.  В постгресе понятно. Но в sqlite как?

Comment: Там же обычный текстовый файл.

Comment: Набросал [код](https://pastebin.com/KfFKnTB9) на C#. На слабом ноутбуке с медленным HDD сто тысяч строк вставляются в среднем за 1,1 - 1,3 секунды. Соль в том, что нужно вручную создать транзакцию: `var tran = conn.BeginTransaction()` - и внутри неё выполнять множество `insert`.

Comment: Сделал `[id] integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL`, чтобы он генерировался в БД и, соответственно, вставлял только два других значения - время осталось фактически таким же.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, не надо делать транзакции, чтобы создать данные одним запросом. Во вторых. Медленнее транзакций, в реальном мире ничего нет. В третьих. Реальные сайты так работают? Нет уж. Делайте 10 000 запросов к базе, и пишите. И засекайте время.

Comment: Не переносите вслепую опыт работы с одной СУБД на другую. С sqlite нужно работать именно так. По умолчанию там каждый запрос оборачивается в транзакцию. Собственно, предлагаю прекратить обсуждение.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, ну зайдёт к тебе на сайт 100 человек. Ты всех в одну транзакцию обернёшь? Бред же. Даже на каждого по отдельности делать транзакции, уже слишком дорого. Конечно прекращай. Твоё замечание, изначально было неуместным.